# pandas crosstab vs sklearn confusion_matrix giving different results

Tags: pandas, crosstab, sklearn-pandas

Just confused why is pandas crosstab returning FP of 1 whereas sklearn's confusion_matrix is returning FP of 0.

Shouldn't the FP also be 0 as indicated correctly by sklearn? Why is pandas showing it differently? Please clarify.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    
data = {'y_Actual':    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        'y_Predicted': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['y_Actual','y_Predicted'])
confusion_matrix = 
pd.crosstab(df['y_Actual'], df['y_Predicted'], rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'])  
print (confusion_matrix)
```

```html
Predicted  0  1
Actual         
1          3  4
```

```
metrics.confusion_matrix(df['y_Actual'], df['y_Predicted'])
```

```html
array([[0, 0],
       [3, 4]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: *"pandas crosstab returning FP of 1"* It doesn't... Note that you don't have a 0 in ground truths so pandas' crosstab doesn't form a row for it. Please change to `'y_Actual':    [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]` and rerun and see what pandas gives...

Comment: Neither is right. It is only display problem of `print(confusion_matrix)`. You can try typing just `confusion_matrix' or check `confusion_matrix.shape`

Comment: 'y_Actual': 0 and 'y_Predicted': 1 --> Shows FP correctly with 1 printed, but reverse case of 'y_Actual': 1 and 'y_Predicted': 0 --> Also shows FP , which is not correct right?

Comment: I mean 'y_Actual': 0 and 'y_Predicted': 1 --> This is correctly printing 1 for FP, whereas 'y_Actual': 1 and 'y_Predicted': 0 --> This is incorrectly printing 1 for FP.